# Терминал vsc, отступ

Tags: javascript, html, css, консоль, visual-studio-code

Столкнулся с проблемой , при открытии терминала , у меня появляется отступ после расположения файла, как его убрать ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/swrnC.jpg

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том , что когда я создаю файл ,  закидываю в vsc , открываю терминал , у меня после расположения файла , появляется пробел , а из-за этого пробела , я не могу закинуть vue cli , как убрать этот пробел ? Мне надо чтобы было вот так PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Site\vue>и я сразу пишу текст , а не PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Site\vue> я пишу текст

Comment: но в целом, если хочется вот прям без пробела - `prompt $P$G` и нажать ентер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, нашел ошибку. [надо не менее 30 символов]